# How to disable the image of a specific UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my `UITableView`, if a section has 0 rows, I tell it to be set up like so:

```
if (top3ArrayForSection.count-1 < 1) {

        // title of the item
        cell.textLabel.text = @"No items found, but we'll keep a lookout for you!";
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@""];
        [cell.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];

}
```

This is so that `detailTextLabel` is blank, and the `cell.imageView` doesn't show. However, the cell ends up showing up like the picture below. The image is blank, but still taking up space, resulting in the `textLabel` being pushed off to the right like that. How can I remove the image all together for that specific cell?

[image]

Comment: Just call `cell.imageView.image = nil;` for the rows that don't have an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a different subclass of UITableViewCell to display the one without the image. That will be a lot easier than trying to move stuff around dynamically.

Comment: I'm already using a subclassed `UITableViewCell`, how would I go about telling it to not include an image?

Comment: There is no reason to create another subclass. Just set `cell.imageView.image = nil;`.

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on @Almo's post:

Create a second variant of your custom table view (you could make it a subclass of your custom table view class; that way you don't have to duplicate code. In your subclass, skip the image and shift the label over.

Another way to do this would be with auto-layout and constraints. you could make the label's left edge link to the right edge of the image view, and pin the label's right edge to the edge of the cell. Then when the image view is zero width, the label would shift over. The problem there is padding. You'd still get the padding from both sides of the image view unless you added custom code to zero out the left edge padding on the image view when the image is empty.